# How many SVD's does a matrix have?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

> If $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with singular values $5$, $4$, and $2$, then there are $9$ distinct singular value decompositions of $A$. True or false?

---

Is there any method to solve this because I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to get started by considering the simplest possible example, in this case a $3\times 3$ matrix with the designated singular values.  If you plan to participate in Math.SE in an on-going fashion, you'll probably want to learn at least the rudiments of posting [typeset mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Oh, I know a lot about latex, I just thought it would be ok to write numbers without putting them in latex, but ok! Also, I'll try to do it that way using an example and then get back to you.

Comment: Actually, how do I make a matrix with the singular values of $5$, $4$, and $2$ from scratch?

Comment: Try writing out the definition of SVD. See what happens if you permute the diagonal entries of singular values. Then count the number of distinct permutations

Comment: Just go through this link. http://rakaposhi.eas.asu.edu/s10-cse494-mailarchive/msg00030.html

Comment: Is $A$ real or complex? For example, $U \Sigma V^T = (-U) \Sigma (-V)^T$.

Comment: @Dr.Disambiguous To see how people typeset something, find an example on Math.SE and left click, select Show Math As->TeX Commands to see.

Comment: @AxyuS I looked at the link but I'm not sure what df, ff, so on are.

Comment: @copper.hat I know how to typeset things. Also, thanks for the tip! I'm assuming $A$ is real.

Comment: I have a question: Does the middle matrix $\Sigma$ need to be in the order of greatest to least singular values, or can it be in any order?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1805191/339790

Comment: @Dr.Disambiguous You must be aware of this equation $A = U S V^{T}$. Those symbols are nothing but different names for the variable of equation written above.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important rule:

- An $n*n$ matrix with n distinct positive singular values has $2^{n}$
  different singular value decompositions (svds).
- An $n*n$ *singular* matrix (one without an inverse) with $n$ distinct
  singular values ($\sigma_{n}$ can be $0$) has $2^{n+1}$ distinct
  svds.
- An $n*n$ matrix with a repeated singular value has $\infty$ svds.

This problem satisfies the first rule, therefore $A$ has $2^{3}=8$ distinct svds.

Answer: **False**

Comment: Are you assuming that the singular values on the main diagonal of $\Sigma$ are in descending order?